# Using narrower DDR RAM than controller

Tags: arm, memory, ram, ddr, sbc

I have some ARM processor that have 72-bit width (8 for ECC) RAM controller.

1. Can I buy eg. two 32bit chips and combine them? If yes then how?
2. Can I buy just one 32bit and pull down rest of data pins on processor?

Processor brief if needed: https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/1211168571391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I buy eg. two 32bit chips and combine them?

I imagine so. The product brief describes ECC as "optional", which indicates to me that it can operate with non-ECC memory:

> The memory system supports the latest DDR4 memories in addition to DDR3 and DDR3L. **Optional ECC support** is provided as well.

In practice, though, this part appears to be designed to operate with very large quantities of memory. (For instance, it advertises "address space beyond 4 GB".) Using it with the bare minimum of memory seems like it'd be a waste of its capabilities.

> If yes then how?

Contact the vendor for a full datasheet. Keep in mind that Broadcom typically only works with large customers; if you just have a few of these parts from a gray-market source, you are probably out of luck.

> Can I buy just one 32bit and pull down rest of data pins on processor?

You'd have to ask the vendor, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for Your response, I found retail seller for these processors, so I won't talk with Broadcom (excluding Datasheet).

Comment: That's not going to work. You will need the datasheet to do anything with this part, and Broadcom will not provide that datasheet to an individual, or to a company which does not intend to buy their parts.

Comment: Actually we are small firm, and w have some investors, so we will see how Broadcom will behave.

Comment: Many ARM SOC chips will work with narrower memory than the chip supports (e.g. 32 bit memory on a 64 bit bus) but this requires that the SOC memory controller be so configured. The Broadcom documents should tell you.